# Jest mock does not return correct value if called in other function

Tags: javascript, lambda, jestjs

I try to test the lambda function, which uses `moment` library. Let's say, I have the following part of lambda function:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(moment().tz("Europe/Warsaw"));
    // rest of the code, does not matter in this case
}
```

In my test file, I try the following approach:

```
jest.mock('moment-timezone', () => {
    const originalMoment = jest.requireActual('moment-timezone');
    return () => ({
        ...originalMoment(),
        tz: jest.fn(() => originalMoment('2024-01-01T12:00:00').tz('Europe/Warsaw')),
    });
});

const {handler} = require('../lambdas/path_to_my_lambda')
const moment = require("moment-timezone");

describe("my_lambda", () => {

    it('should use the mocked date', async () => {
        const now = moment().tz("Europe/Warsaw");
        console.log(now);
        await handler({})
    });
});
```

In this example, `console.log` returns `Moment<2024-01-01T12:00:00+01:00>`, which is correct. However, the `console.log` from lambda function does return current date (in my case, it is `Moment<2024-01-16T07:11:34+01:00>`).

I tried different approaches from some other posts, but neither of them worked.
My goal is to make the `moment().tz("Europe/Warsaw")` return mocked value in my lambda function, so I can correctly test all the scenarios.